# Show placeholder and icon when TextField isEmpty

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to add an icon ( SFSymbol) called "exclamationmark.triangle" if the field is empty to identify that it's a required text field. Below is the method I used. It works, but not properly. When the user clicks on a text field and starts typing after the first character keyboard goes away, so the user has to retap to continue typing.

```
if name.isEmpty {
   HStack {
      TextField("First & Last Name", text: $name)
      Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
   }
} else {
   TextField("First & Last Name", text: $name)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("First & Last Name", text: $name)
            name.isEmpty ? Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle") : nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upon entering a character in the ``TextField`` it removes the entire text field.

Comment: What do you mean by that? When you start typing, the placeholder and icon image goes away, and you will only see the text you entered. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: The entire TextField disappears upon entering a character into the TextField.

Comment: I stand corrected, the above answer does work appropriately. My code was improperly formatted thus, not working properly. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see that behavior. If you are trying to say that you only see the text and nothing else, that's because of background color and TextField's background color are the same.  Try using the `.background()` modifier to your TextField and see. Let me know! NP.